# Hbase Java Api is not persisting any integer value

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am trying to insert age as number int Bytes.toBytes(44) to HTable but value is not being persisted. Same is happening with Row key also. I am using Cloudera Quick Start VM:
Here is my code :

```
package com.sohi.put;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HColumnDescriptor;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ZooKeeperConnectionException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Get;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;

public class TestClass {    
public static void main(String[] args) throws MasterNotRunningException,       ZooKeeperConnectionException, IOException {

    Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();

    HBaseAdmin hBaseAdmin = new HBaseAdmin(conf);

    TableName  tableName = TableName.valueOf("SampleDataTable") ;

    HTableDescriptor tableDescriptor = new HTableDescriptor(tableName) ;

    HColumnDescriptor personalColFam = new HColumnDescriptor("personal");
    HColumnDescriptor officeColFam = new HColumnDescriptor("office");

    tableDescriptor.addFamily(personalColFam);
    tableDescriptor.addFamily(officeColFam);


    if(!hBaseAdmin.tableExists(tableName)){
        hBaseAdmin.createTable(tableDescriptor);
    }

    HTable hTable = new HTable(conf, tableName);

    byte [] row  = Bytes.toBytes(121);
    byte [] personalCf  = Bytes.toBytes("personal");
    byte [] officeCf  = Bytes.toBytes("office");
    byte [] qual1  = Bytes.toBytes("name");
    byte [] qual2  = Bytes.toBytes("age");
    byte [] qual3  = Bytes.toBytes("location");

    byte [] name  = Bytes.toBytes("John");
    byte [] age  = Bytes.toBytes(44);
    byte [] loc  = Bytes.toBytes("USA");

    Put data = new Put(row);
    data.add(personalCf, qual1, name);
    data.add(personalCf, qual2, age);
    data.add(officeCf, qual3, loc);

    hTable.put(data);

    // giving issue with integer values like age and row key
    System.out.println("Done");


}
```

}

Here is the output :

[image: Put Output]

Note the Key value and Age Value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hue's HBase Browser does a good job of displaying strings correctly - but **not** other data types. The reason is pretty simple: **HBase doesn't know what data type you've stored - but you do**! For example, if you read 8 bytes from an HBase column, it could be a 64-bit integer or a float or 8 single byte characters.

Now, to come back to your question: **Your code is working perfectly fine**!

The comma you're seeing is ASCII representation of `44` (see http://www.ascii-code.com/)

When you read the data back from HBase in your code, use `Bytes.toInt()` and you'll be able to correctly read it as integer `44`.

Comment: Sure Manu . With Pleasure

Answer (score 0):

It is always recommended to use string. But if required we can use numeric too. For that, try uing the wrapper class - BigInteger.

```
byte[] val = BigInteger.valueOf(44).toByteArray();
```

Comment: Still It is adding comma instead of actual value. I am new to HBase . Why it is only considering String value ?

Comment: The content will be Base64 encoded.. You need to decode the content of integer by Base64 to get the exact same value..  In case of string it is handled by default automatically.